# What are other sources of information about Gadhelyn?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, religions-and-deities, greyhawk

#### Backstory

I'm planning to play a Half-Drow Warlock (Hexblade) whose patron is a lesser elvish deity.

Long story short: *the character escaped the Underdark under guidance of its patron. The patron I chose is Gadhelyn, a CN deity from the [Seldarine](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mtof/elves#ElfDeitiesTheSeldarine) (Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, page 43) whose province fits perfectly with it: Independence and Outlawry (as my char is an outlaw from its original society).*

#### Problem

The problem with Gadhelyn is that I can't find any information about him. A quick search on the internet show that he is from the Greyhawk setting – an elf that achieved godhood through its deeds in life – but that's about it.

**Where can I find out more information about Gadhelyn?**

I'm not looking for suggestions like "*choose a god with more info and create a cleric*".

**I'll take suggestions from sourcebooks/material (from 5e or previous), fiction, multimedia, or any other D&D source.** Suggestions of other patrons (from official sources) that fit my character backstory are welcome too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an *Official Listing of Deities for Use in the Campaign* document for the RPGA's Living Greyhawk campaign. Its version 2.0, dating back to March 2005 (D&D 3.5e), is still [downloadable from](http://www.wizards.com/rpga/downloads/LG_Deities.zip) the Wizards of the Coast website. Quoting parts from that document:

> Areas of Concern/Portfolio: Independence, Outlawry, Feasting, Hunting
>
> Titles: The Archer, Lord of the Wildwood
>
> Holy Symbol: A leaf-shaped arrowhead
>
> Gadhelyn (Gad-THEL-en) the Archer is an old name in elven mythology. Once part of the traditional Fey Mysteries, he is now largely forgotten by the elf-kindreds, save among the grugach. ... Gadhelyn is the ideal of the noble outlaw, with a court of unruly but loyal subjects. He recognizes no value in family lineage, but admires only individual skill and merit. ... His worshippers are most commonly grugach, but also include a number of wood elves, and even a few half-elves and humans revere him and participate in his festivals. His followers are the bane of wealthy travelers in the woodlands, but they are truly dangerous only if attacked, or if their forests are despoiled.

Comment: Nice stuff! The document also mentions its sources, which includes Living Greyhawk Journal #3, which is the one reference about Gadhelyn. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [Greyhawk wiki](https://greyhawkplus.wikia.com/wiki/Gadhelyn) has a smidgen of info about Gadheylyn

> **Gadhelyn** is an elven Hero-deity who was sponsored for ascension by an unknown patron. He is an elf of sharp features and long yellow
>   hair, and his eyes are bright, piercing green.
>
> Gadhelyn teaches his few followers to seek joy and pleasure in all
>   seasons, and eschews social caste and status in favour of individual
>   merit and accomplishment. He is a hero still venerated among the
>   grugach, but otherwise mostly forgotten.

[1d4chan](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Gadhelyn) has a smidge.

> **Gadhelyn** (pronounced gad-THEL-len), is the elven and Oerthian Hero-God
>   of feasting, hunting, independence, and outlawry. Once a part of the
>   larger elven pantheon, the Lord of the Wildwood has mostly been
>   forgotten, with only the grugach worshipping him.
>
> **Dogma**
>
> Rejoice in the springtime, make merry in the summer, feast in autumn,
>   and dream in winter's shadow. At the court of the Lord of the
>   Wildwood, knights are knaves and the rude are royal. Let all who would
>   enter the forest bring a gift to the Lord of the Wildwood; but beware,
>   if it is not pleasing, he shall take what he will in its stead. When
>   the first arrow strikes the heart, it is a noble wound; when a second
>   must be shot, it is fitting that the hunter should become the hunted.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greyhawk_deities#G) has a smidge in its listing of Greyhawk deities.

> **Gadhelyn the Archer** (Gad-THEL-en) is the elven hero-god of
>   Independence, Outlawry, Feasting, and Hunting. His symbol is a
>   leaf-shaped arrowhead. Gadhelyn is a very old figure in elven myth,
>   once a part of the Fey Mysteries but now largely forgotten except
>   among the grugach. He is depicted as an elf with sharp features, long
>   yellow hair, and vivid green eyes. He wears rough clothing of fur and
>   hide, of colors to match the season. Gadhelyn is still a potent hero
>   among the grugach. Sylvan elves and even a few half-elves and humans
>   revere him and participate in his rites. Followers of Gadhelyn prey on
>   the wealthy who dare to cross their woodlands, but they are not truly
>   dangerous unless attacked, or if their forests are despoiled.